# Need help in tweaking CSS to match given specifications

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a navigation bar using CSS3. A snapshot of the expected result is shown below

[image]

I have used `<nav>` `<li>` `<ul>` tags to create the skeleton for the page and added some CSS3 to simulate the desired output. The products dropdown menu has to be shown when the mouse hovers on the "Products" title in the navigation bar. Include appropriate color changes as indicated in the snapshot.

The CSS3 scheme is given below

[image]

Here is the code that I have tried so far but I am getting some error like Fail 1 - CSS elements for  is wrong. Please help me understand where the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Create a simple Navigation bar</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    nav {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      margin-right: 20px;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    a {
      a: link;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li:hover ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 200px;
      background-color: green;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    li:hover ul li a:link {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 30px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: yellow;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Telecom</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Energy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your post, I would edit myself but I can't tell what you intended

Comment: CSS to hide `ul` children of `li` elements when not hovering is missing. Perhaps the marking software is not smart enough to give good feedback. The CSS to color the text correctly is also missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Here is my best attempt to figure out what the spec described - I have added comments in the CSS to help you map it back to the spec.

As to what was specifically wrong with your code - it's a little hard to tell because there is a lot of extra stuff going on. It usually helps to keep things simple in CSS (and pretty much any code really). I started from scratch and reproduced what the spec arrived to get the solution below.

Bonus Tip: Using the Chome Dev Tools (or other similar tools specific to your browser) can help you debug how the CSS is being applied to each element.

```css
/*
The nav section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
nav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
}

/*
The li section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* This is missing from the spec. Used to hide the submenu initially */
li>ul {
  display: none;
}


/*
The li:hover ul section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
}


/*
The li:hover ul li a:link section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
li:hover>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

/*
The a a:link section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*
The a a:hover section in the spec. Pretty much verbatim as the spec describes it
*/
a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Create a simple Navigation bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Telecom</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Energy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I came to know my mistakes and now te error has been solved